# How to Count Results of SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I am running a popular open sourced LMS called Moodle which has a MySQL database behind it.  I have a functioning Query already written that returns a listing of all of our employees and a Sum of their scores on 9 required courses called IT Policy courses.  The idea being that if they have a 900 I know they have passed all 9, 700 means they have completed 7, and so forth.  Below is that Query.

```
SELECT u.firstname AS 'First' , u.lastname AS 'Last', cc.name AS 'Category', 
ROUND(SUM(gg.finalgrade),0) AS Grade
FROM prefix_course AS c
JOIN prefix_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
JOIN prefix_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
JOIN prefix_grade_grades AS gg ON 
JOIN prefix_grade_items AS gi ON gi.id = gg.itemid
JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.category 
WHERE  gi.courseid = c.id AND cc.name = 'IT Policies' AND gi.itemtype = 'course'
GROUP BY u.lastname,u.firstname
ORDER BY grade
```

My Question is This.  I want a summary report that counts how many people have each score.  For example 102 people have a 900.  7 people have an 800, 14 people have a 700, 0 people have a 600, ...., 72 people have no scores at all, etc.

This query doesn't need to display anything but a score and a count of how many people have that score.  I've worked on this for a couple of days and taken a number of approaches.  I just can't seem to get it right though.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank You,
Harvy

Comment: Er, this isn't your query. But anyway, why does '900' = 'passed 9', as opposed to, say, '9'?

Answer (score 0):

Save your query as a view. Then run a SQL query on view (say 'marksheet') as follows :

```
SELECT Grade, COUNT(First) FROM marksheet GROUP BY Grade
```